# Как сделать подключение между контейнерами и подключение из вне?

Tags: docker-compose

Я собираю докер ([отсюда](https://github.com/rajkrs/Docker_AspDotNetCore_SqlServer)) изменил сеть чтобы можно было подключать контейнер к контейнеру. Но почему то не могу с компа подключиться к контейнеру и контейнеры не могут соединиться:
docker-compose:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApi/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db  
ports:
  - "8000:80"     
expose:  
  - 80
  
  db:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
    container_name: webapisqldb
    environment:
        ACCEPT_EULA: Y
        SA_PASSWORD: "Bassword@123"
    ports:  
      - '1433:1433'  
    expose:  
      - 1433
    volumes:  
      - sql-data:/var/opt/mssql3  

volumes:
      sql-data:
networks:
  outside:
    external: true
```

docker:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0.0-preview7-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0.100-preview7-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApi/WebApi.csproj", "WebApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApi/WebApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApi"
RUN dotnet build "WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]
```

Есть у кого пример, чтобы подключить docker с бд и чтобы все работало?

Comment: К какому контейнеру вы не можете подключиться?

Comment: Я не могу отправить запрос, из windows к webapi контейнеру

То что они не подключались друг к другу, я решил

Comment: У вас для webapi не проброшен порт: элемент ports в docker-compose файле. Для примера посмотрите как описан ваш контейнер для бд.

Comment: Но я же в докере указываю, EXPOSE 80

Не сработало. Как я написал изменил в вопросе

Comment: Попробовал через swagger отправить запрос и получил: ECONNREFUSED 
Кажется ошибка сети, какая-то надо менять docker-compose

Comment: А вы к какому порту обращаетесь?

Comment: @ArtemBerezovski, к 80 порту

Answer (score 1, accepted):

80 - порт на котором крутится приложение внутри контейнера. Если вы хотите достучаться до приложения из хоста, вам нужно обращаться к 8000 порту.

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает, мне надо получается expose тоже 8000??

Comment: Запустил ваш пример - всё работает. Сделайте docker-compose down, уберите все ваши кастомные настройки и поднимите контейнеры - webapp будет на порту 52743 (описано в readme). И ещё, обратите внимание, там лежит docker-compose.override.yml. Он используется для переопределения настроек в docker-compose. Про него можно почитать, например [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/337688/).

Comment: Вы это делали на linux, windows docker toolbox или windows desktop?

Comment: Windows, docker 19.03.8, docker-compose 1.25.5

Comment: Я не смог сделать по нормальному desktop, и мне кажется удобно пользоваться через консоль. По этому сделал docker toolbox.

Походу из за этого проблема и не получается отправить запрос(

Comment: Docker toolbox использует docker-machine, которая создаёт виртуальную машину с linux. При создании этой вм docker-machine должен выводить в лог IP виртуальной машины. Вам нужно подключаться не к localhost, а к IP виртуальной машины.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109293/discussion-between-chilo5432-and-artem-berezovski).

Comment: Случайно на чатик нажал. Так тоже делал. Результат тот же, там как я понимаю по дефолту одна и та же ip выводится 192.168.99.100

Comment: Переходите в чат.